# How to sync events between 2 google calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

We recently registered a Google Business apps account and created a calendar for each employee. We book them appointments when they are free (meaning we read/write in the agenda).

Some employees already have their own personnal Google account with a calendar. Their personal events must show in their business calendar so we book only when they are really free.

How can I ensure that their personnal events show when I query their business calendar? And how can I ensure that if they only check their personnal calendar they will see their business events?

I don't want to just see the events on the same agenda if I log in to Google Calendar, I need a real sync of the events. I can't find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. So, your use case is, you are creating a business calendar for each customer. And for the customers who already have google calendars, you will create business calendar too. But you want the personal calendar to be synched with business calendar rite?

Comment: If that is the case, then I don't think you can sync events between two different calendars. Better option would be, have user give you permissions to his own calendar. Try to send events.list request for that calendar to decide when user is busy. Also, check this link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/BImdP8Gui1s